# Why isn't jQuery working with ASP.NET for me?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

This doesn't work and I don't understand why, I have tried that code on W3schools and that works, I think the problem might be the reference or something, I'm new to ASP.NET.

ASP Code(Master Page)

```
<script src="./Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bt_insertar").click(function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Index.aspx

```
<td class="style4">
    <asp:Button ID="bt_insertar" runat="server" Text="Insertar" Width="71px" 
    onclick="bt_insertar_Click" style="height: 26px" />
</td>
```

Comment: What is ClientIdMode set to? Have you inspected the html to ensure that you're actually getting the id generated that you think you're getting?

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest you might want to try the free "Try jQuery" course from CodeSchool if you are new to jQuery and JavaScript as it gives an excellent introduction to the library which will help give you the confidence and skills to write jQuery code. http://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the `ID` you give your `runat="server"` control isn't the `id` that ends up on the DOM element. You can get the ID that ASP.Net generates from [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property on the server-side control object. E.g., change:

```
$("#bt_insertar").click(...
```

to

```
$("#<%= bt_insertar.ClientID%>").click(...
```

...if that code is in a page ASP.Net parses (as opposed to an external JavaScript file).

As of ASP.Net 4, you can control this behavior via the [`ClientIDMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx). For instance, if you use the [`Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) mode (`control.ClientIDMode = CLientIDMode.Static;`), then the `ID` is in fact passed through as-is. But the default value for `ClientIDMode` is `Predictable`, which modifies the `ID` you use.

Comment: This property is only available in ASP.NET 4 and above for clarity. The purpose of the concatenated ID in ASP.NET is to prevent duplicate IDs when you are using template controls or repeating elements/user controls. Use static IDs with care within user controls or templates to avoid this duplication.

Comment: I am indeed - ClientID has been available since ASP.NET 1 to clarify the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To Bind jquery function to Asp.net Server control you have to write code this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#<%= bt_insertar.ClientID %>').click(function () {
          alert("Handler for .click() called.");
      });


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

1. In your JQuery include statement the src should be `src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"` instead of `src="./Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"`
2. You don't really need to bind click event in your `document.ready` event instead you can include `OnClientClick="bt_insertar_Click();"` in your `asp:Button`

and then you can define your `function bt_insertar_Click()`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function bt_insertar_Click() {
       alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    }
    </script>
```

It is a better programming practice to use a separate .js file for you web page so you can move all the relevant js functions to this js file and then include it like you did with the jquery file.