# Jquery undefined element after DOM ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined, document-ready

I am attempting to run an method after the DOM is ready, but cannot access the element. It is coming back as undefined. The code is below. I know the element is accessible because code ran after the DOM elements processes fine. The alert in the separate js file come back undefined. The alert at the bottom of the html returns the correct value.

HTML

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" inherits="test.master"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html> 
    <head runat="server">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/master.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(ajaxStuff('<%= varthing %>'));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="hdr">
                <div id="hdr_logo">
                    <img alt="Logo" id="hdr_logo_img" src="images/logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="hdr_toolslct">
                    <div id="hdr_toolslct_wrpr">
                        <span id="hdr_toolslct_cursys"><span id="hdr_toolslct_cursys_payer" runat="server"></span> - <span id="hdr_toolslct_cursys_prov"></span></span><br />
                        Hello <span id="hdr_toolslct_name" class="hdr_toolslct_name" runat="server"></span>!&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Thing1:&nbsp;
                        <select id="hdr_toolslct_gp" runat="server">
                        </select>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Thing2:&nbsp;
                        <span id="hdr_toolslct_prov_wrpr"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="nav" class="nav" runat="server">
                <div id="nav_home" class="nav_tab">Home</div>
                <div id="nav_worklist" class="nav_tab">Worklist</div>
                <div id="nav_reporting" class="nav_tab">Reporting</div>
                <div id="nav_splits" class="nav_tab">Splits</div>
                <div id="nav_users" class="nav_tab">Users</div>
                <div id="nav_import" class="nav_tab">Import</div>
            </div>
            <div id="cntnt">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cntnt_phldr" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div id="ftr">
                If you experience issues with this tool, please stop using it. I'm not going to help.
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert($("#ftr").html());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function ajaxStuff(vartest) {
    alert($("#ftr").html());
}
```

ViewSource

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html> 
    <head><title>
    test
</title><link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/master.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(ajaxStuff('no'));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="hdr">
                <div id="hdr_logo">
                    <img alt="Logo" id="hdr_logo_img" src="images/logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="hdr_toolslct">
                    <div id="hdr_toolslct_wrpr">
                        <span id="hdr_toolslct_cursys"><span id="ctl00_hdr_toolslct_cursys_payer">Mcaid</span> - <span id="hdr_toolslct_cursys_prov"></span></span><br />
                        Hello <span id="ctl00_hdr_toolslct_name" class="hdr_toolslct_name">Name Name</span>!&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Thing1:&nbsp;
                        <select name="ctl00$hdr_toolslct_gp" id="ctl00_hdr_toolslct_gp">
    <option selected="selected" value="OP1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="OP2">Option 2</option>
</select>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Thing2:&nbsp;
                        <span id="hdr_toolslct_prov_wrpr"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ctl00_nav" class="nav">
                <div id="nav_home" class="nav_tab">Home</div>
                <div id="nav_worklist" class="nav_tab">Worklist</div>
                <div id="nav_reporting" class="nav_tab">Reporting</div>
                <div id="nav_splits" class="nav_tab">Splits</div>
                <div id="nav_users" class="nav_tab">Users</div>
                <div id="nav_import" class="nav_tab">Import</div>
            </div>
            <div id="cntnt">




            </div>
            <div id="ftr">
                If you experience issues with this tool, please stop using it. I'm not going to help
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert($("#ftr").html());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please wrap `$(ajaxStuff('<%= varthing %>'));` with jQuery document ready callback.

Comment: You forgot `$(document)ready(...)`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Did that, same result

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, `$(ajaxStuff('<%= varthing %>'));` is correctly wrapped in DOM ready ....

Comment: try alerting the value of `<%= varthing %>` directly there.

Comment: @shaunakde Did that, same result

Comment: @shaunakde I'm not attempting to alert that value at all. I'm trying to access elements of the DOM, which are coming back undefined.

Comment: The parameter is irrelevant ... just causing confusion. Can you view the page source and confirm there's an element with id="ftr"?

Comment: So can you paste your final code here(The code that produced using server and sent to the browser, You can open "View Source" and copy that)?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi View source added. I've tried with several other DOM elements as well with the same result. There is an element with id="ftr"

Comment: Sure that the script at the bottom is the one that works and not the other way round? Try wrapping `$(...)` on both scripts.

Comment: @theHacker I'm sure. Without the script at the bottom, I get an alert of "undefined". With it, I get an alert of "undefined" and then an alert with the html code I expect.

Comment: @steventnorris, See my answer: `('no')` or `()` causes the function to be invoked immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please bear in mind that the reason you're getting undefined is because the function `ajaxStuff` is being invoked immediately. If you use any of the following forms, it should work as expected. `()`, or `(arguments)` invokes the function right away:

```
$(ajaxStuff);
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(ajaxStuff);
```

Or

```
$(function() {
    ajaxStuff('no');
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ajaxStuff('no');
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/J9XaB/)

Comment: Terrific. That works fine. Now, why does jquery/javascript work that way? That seems rather unintuitive. Is this just an odd quirk of javascript/jquery or does it have a purpose?

Comment: Most people 'spell' out the `function(){ ...  }` in DOM ready as in the 3rd and 4th example above; so they do not get into such issues. However, when you do not 'spell' it out, you must be careful not to use `()`, for that's how you call the function. I think this might be somewhat helpful: http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043779/

Answer (score 0):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vD5sk/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">hello</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    alert($('#test').html());
});
```

Comment: This is essentially what I've done. My ready event is not in a separate file. I tried that too, with no changed results.

Comment: @steventnorris can you put your code in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Using the viewsource and js, it seems to work in jsfiddle, but I am still getting an undefined as if it is not running on DOM ready, but before. http://jsfiddle.net/j6uz4/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the jQuery ready event:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Your code might work with:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
 alert($("#ftr").html());
});
```

Or

```
$(function() {
   // Handler for .ready() called.
   alert($("#ftr").html());
});
```

in the JavaScript part.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NU6GT/2/)

UPDATE:

As this is not working, you should try to analyze the DOM that is generated:

```
$(function() {
   // Handler for .ready() called.
   console.log($("body").html());
});
```

Maybe there IDs are changed? Or something like that? You tell us :D

Comment: My current syntax follows your second example. I've also tried the first. I did not have it offloaded into a separate file, tried that, same result.

Comment: This is odd... Your ViewResource is perfectly correct. If you try it on fiddle it works :S. Are you using ASP .NET with C#? Does it have any 'OnLoaded' on the C# part? Maybe you have to trigger that event.. But still it's very strange because the result html is correct :S

Comment: I'm not using an OnLoaded in C#, but I am using ASP.NET with C# codebehind. All that I'm doing server-side is some processing to build the select list out.

Comment: I think it's related with C# codebehind but I can't tell where is the problem, maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632425/why-jquery-is-not-working-with-asp-net solves your problem. You should add C# and ASP .NET tags so as to get .NET experts here! :D